# ROOM ANDORID: error: Cannot figure out how to read this field from a cursor

Tags: android, android-room

в БД SQLite содержаться три таблицы 1)employee 2)skills 3)departments. Идея такая - в таблице employee хранятся такие данные как  id, name, last_name, salary. Также у есть employee есть такие данные как skill  и department но их может быть несколько у одного employee по этому я создал две отдельный таблицы skills и departments и привязал их с помощью ключе к таблице employee где первичный ключ у employee  является id. Теперь с помощью id мне нужно вывести на экран всю информацию об employee включая его skills которых может 
быть несколько и departments. Весь процесс я реализовываю с помощью библиотеки ROOM.

Вот запрос который я делаю

```
@Query("SELECT employ.id ,employ.name ,employ.last_name, employ.salary, " +
        "skill.skill, department.department_name FROM employ INNER JOIN skill,department " +
        "ON employ.id = :id AND skill.employ_id = :id AND department.employ_id = :id ")
AllAboutEmployee getAllAboutEmployee(String id);
```

Вот класс AllAboutEmployee, объект которого принимает результат запроса

```
public class AllAboutEmployee {

@ColumnInfo(name = "id")
private String id;

@ColumnInfo(name = "name")
private String name;

@ColumnInfo(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@ColumnInfo(name = "salary")
private String salary;

@ColumnInfo(name = "department_name")
private List<String> departmentsList; // ПРОБЛЕМА В ЭТОЙ СТРОКЕ

@ColumnInfo(name = "skill")
private List<String> skillList; // ПРОБЛЕМА В ЭТОЙ СТРОКЕ

public AllAboutEmployee(String id, String name, String lastName, String salary, List<String> departmentsList, List<String> skillList) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.salary = salary;
    this.departmentsList = departmentsList;
    this.skillList = skillList;
}
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public void setSalary(String salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}

public List<String> getDepartmentsList() {
    return departmentsList;
}

public void setDepartmentsList(List<String> departmentsList) {
    this.departmentsList = departmentsList;
}

public List<String> getSkillList() {
    return skillList;
}

public void setSkillList(List<String> skillList) {
    this.skillList = skillList;
}
```

}

Получается в классе AllAboutEmployee находятся два поля с типа List это для того чтоб поместить туда несколько skills и несколько departments. именно в этих полях и возникает ошибка.
Заранее благодарю за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
public class AllAboutEmployee {

    @Embedded 
    private Employ employ; //Employ - класс, помеченный как Entity

    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "employ_id")
    private List<Department> departmentsList; //Department - класс, помеченный как Entity

    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "employ_id")
    private List<Skill> skillList; //Skill- класс, помеченный как Entity

    public AllAboutEmployee(Employ employ) {
        this.employ = employ;
    }

    public Employ getEmploy() {
        return employ;
    }

    public List<Department> getDepartmentsList() {
        return departmentsList;
    }

    public void setDepartmentsList(List<Department> departmentsList) {
        this.departmentsList = departmentsList;
    }

    public List<Skill> getSkillList() {
        return skillList;
    }

    public void setSkillList(List<Skill> skillList) {
        this.skillList = skillList;
    }
}
```

Запрос будет вида

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM employ WHERE employ.id = :id")
AllAboutEmployee getAllAboutEmployee(String id);
```

Делал такое уже давно и на Kotlin, а не на Java, так что не уверен, что взлетит сразу)

Comment: Работает отлично. благодарю за помощь. Получается для того чтоб вывести всю полученную информацию от запроса я должен объявить переменную типа AllAboutEmployee, присвоить ей ссылку на объект который возвращает метод getAllAboutEmployee(String id), далее мне нужно объявить два списка,один будет содержать класс Skill  а второй класс Department и присвоить этим двум спискам ссылки списков которые содержит объект AllAboutEmployee. Так получается? Вот скрин кода который я написал для вывода информации об employee  на экран http://prntscr.com/rw96hx